# Get a JSON result based on a Ilist<int> in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I need to build a string like "1-2-3-4-5", from an IList< int > returned by an MVC Action.

Action:

```
public virtual JsonResult AdvancedSearch(AdAdvancedSearchViewModel asViewModel)
{
    IList<int> adIds = new List<int>();

    try
    {
        var asDto = Mapper.Map<AdAdvancedSearchViewModel, AdAdvancedSearchDto>(asViewModel);

        adIds = _adService.AdvancedSearch(asDto);
    }
    catch
    {
        adIds = null;
    }

    return Json(adIds);
}
```

Javascript function that processes the result:

```
function onAdAdvancedSearchSuccess(jsonAdListIds)
{
    $("#adAdvancedSearchListForm #ids").val(jsonAdListIds);
}
```

The problem is that I get a string like this "[1,2,3,4]" in the "#adAdvancedSearchListForm #ids" HTML input, and I need to get "1-2-3-4", any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is returning an array which is expected since you are converting a list.

Try parsing the array into the string:

```
var r = jsonAdListIds[0];
for (var i = 1; i < jsonAdListIds.length; i++) {
  r += '-' + jsonAdListIds[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it at the client side, simply iterate throught the result array and build the string you want.

```
 $.getJSON("yourURL", { Name: "John", Loc: "2pm" },function(result){
     var str=""; 
     $.each(result,function(i,item){
       str=str+"-"+item;
     });
    alert(str);
 });
```

Assuming `Name` and Loc are the properties of your viewmodel.

If you want to do it on the server side, you may use `String.Join` method to build the string representation you want. You may need to update the return type of your action method.

```
public string AdvancedSearch(AdAdvancedSearchViewModel asViewModel)
{
  List<int> adIds = new List<int>();
  //fill the list
  var resutlStr= String.Join("-",adIds.ToArray());
  return resutlStr;  
}
```

**I prefer to keep my action method returns JSON** result instead of this string represetnation because an action method which returns JSON can be used in many places compared to this concrete string return implementation.

Comment: My understanding is an AJAX response needs a `JsonResult` so this might not work.

Comment: ajax can receive strings also. But the ideal solution is to have your server side method returns JSON because it can be used in many places

Comment: Hi thanks, I prefer @beautifulcoder answer for the simpliest way to adapt to my code. Thanks you anyway